# Shopify Scripts -

Tags: shopify

I would like to combine two example scripts that are provided by Shopify:

(https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/examples/line-item-scripts#tagged-customer-discount)
(https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/examples/line-item-scripts#product-discount)

So that a discount only applies to products that have a certain tag (e.g. discount-product) for customers that a certain tag (customer-discount).

I've made several attempts at this but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's an example of an attempt to combine the two scripts:

```
# ================================ Customizable Settings ================================
# ================================================================
# Discounts by Customer Tag
#
# If a customer is tagged (or not, depending on the setting below)
# with the entered tag(s), the entered discount will be applied to
# each item in the cart.
#
#   - 'customer_tag_match_type' determines whether we look for the customer
#     to be tagged with any of the entered tags or not. Can be:
#       - ':include' to check if the customer is tagged
#       - ':exclude' to make sure the customer isn't tagged
#   - 'customer_tags' is a list of tags to identify qualified
#     customers
#   - 'discount_type' is the type of discount to provide. Can be
#     either:
#       - ':percent'
#       - ':dollar'
#   - 'discount_amount' is the percentage/dollar discount to
#     apply (per item)
#   - 'discount_message' is the message to show when a discount
#     is applied
# ================================================================
DISCOUNTS_FOR_CUSTOMER_TAG = [
  {
    customer_tag_match_type: :include,
    customer_tags: ["VIP"],
    product_selector_match_type: :include,
    product_selector_type: :tag,
    product_selectors: ["your_tag"],
    discount_type: :percent,
    discount_amount: 20,
    discount_message: "Discount for VIP customers!",
  },
]

# ================================ Script Code (do not edit) ================================
# ================================================================
# CustomerTagSelector
#
# Finds whether the supplied customer has any of the entered tags.
# ================================================================
class CustomerTagSelector
  def initialize(match_type, tags)
    @comparator = match_type == :include ? 'any?' : 'none?'
    @tags = tags.map { |tag| tag.downcase.strip }
  end

  def match?(customer)
    customer_tags = customer.tags.map { |tag| tag.downcase.strip }
    (@tags & customer_tags).send(@comparator)
  end
end

# ================================ Script Code (do not edit) ================================
# ================================================================
# ProductSelector
#
# Finds matching products by the entered criteria.
# ================================================================
class ProductSelector
  def initialize(match_type, selector_type, selectors)
    @match_type = match_type
    @comparator = match_type == :include ? 'any?' : 'none?'
    @selector_type = selector_type
    @selectors = selectors
  end

  def match?(line_item)
    if self.respond_to?(@selector_type)
      self.send(@selector_type, line_item)
    else
      raise RuntimeError.new('Invalid product selector type')
    end
  end

  def tag(line_item)
    product_tags = line_item.variant.product.tags.map { |tag| tag.downcase.strip }
    @selectors = @selectors.map { |selector| selector.downcase.strip }
    (@selectors & product_tags).send(@comparator)
  end

  def type(line_item)
    @selectors = @selectors.map { |selector| selector.downcase.strip }
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include?(line_item.variant.product.product_type.downcase.strip)
  end

  def vendor(line_item)
    @selectors = @selectors.map { |selector| selector.downcase.strip }
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include?(line_item.variant.product.vendor.downcase.strip)
  end

  def product_id(line_item)
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include?(line_item.variant.product.id)
  end

  def variant_id(line_item)
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include?(line_item.variant.id)
  end

  def all(line_item)
    true
  end
end


# ================================================================
# DiscountApplicator
#
# Applies the entered discount to the supplied line item.
# ================================================================
class DiscountApplicator
  def initialize(discount_type, discount_amount, discount_message)
    @discount_type = discount_type
    @discount_message = discount_message

    @discount_amount = if discount_type == :percent
      1 - (discount_amount * 0.01)
    else
      Money.new(cents: 100) * discount_amount
    end
  end

  def apply(line_item)
    new_line_price = if @discount_type == :percent
      line_item.line_price * @discount_amount
    else
      [line_item.line_price - (@discount_amount * line_item.quantity), Money.zero].max
    end

    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @discount_message)
  end
end

# ================================================================
# DiscountForCustomerTagCampaign
#
# If we have a "matching" customer (by tag), the entered discount
# is applied.
# ================================================================
class DiscountForCustomerTagCampaign
  def initialize(discounts)
    @discounts = discounts
  end

  def run(cart)
    return unless cart.customer&.tags

    @discounts.each do |discount|
      customer_tag_selector = CustomerTagSelector.new(discount[:customer_tag_match_type], discount[:customer_tags])

      next unless customer_tag_selector.match?(cart.customer)

      discount_applicator = DiscountApplicator.new(
        discount[:discount_type],
        discount[:discount_amount],
        discount[:discount_message]
      )
    @campaigns.each do |campaign|
      product_selector = ProductSelector.new(
        campaign[:product_selector_match_type],
        campaign[:product_selector_type],
        campaign[:product_selectors],
      )


      cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
        discount_applicator.apply(line_item)
      end
    end
  end
end

CAMPAIGNS = [
  DiscountForCustomerTagCampaign.new(DISCOUNTS_FOR_CUSTOMER_TAG),
]

CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.cart)
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

Comment: What specifically did you try and where did you get into trouble? Please be more specific, so we can help you. We cannot solve your problem, if it's too broad.

Comment: @user1438038   I've updated the original post with an example of attempting to combine the scripts.